# How to add id of one table in a column of another table using azure mobile services script?

Tags: javascript, azure, azure-mobile-services

I have two tables A and B, when I place an order data is save in table A and the id generated in table A is saved in the FKid column of table B. I am using azure mobile services to achieve this. I also want to do it on the server side script because it is agile.

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at the example shown in the post at http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosfigueira/archive/2012/09/11/supporting-complex-types-in-azure-mobile-services-clients-implementing-1-n-table-relationships.aspx. Basically, here's how you accomplish this:

- Client sends an insert request to table A, and one of the properties is an array of elements to be inserted in table B
- At the server side, you first remove the array of elements of type B from the item, since complex types cannot be stored in the server database, saving them into a local variable
- After finishing the insert operation (i.e., in the success handler for the options object passed to the `request.execute` call), you'll have the id of the item in the table A (the foreign key)
- Now loop through the elements that should be inserted in the table B, set the foreign key to the appropriate value, then insert them into the table B.

Comment: Thanks for the reply,I ve been able to do it through your method, but still  I am facing one issue. I need to have transactions state in server script. Can you give me an example of beginTransaction, rollback and commit on server side script.

Comment: If you need transactions, then you should use the [mssql object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/jj554212.aspx) to create the operations yourself. Transactions are not supported in the regular objects in the node.js runtime. You can also consider taking a look at the .NET runtime, where you can use Entity Framework's support for transacted inserts.

Comment: Can you give me a link of an example showing how to use beginTransaction, rollback and commit on server side java script.

Comment: I have started to use beginTransaction but I am stuck at one point. I need to get the id of the last item inserted in transaction while commit has not being called.